# Select 1 random row and n number of rows rows after it

Tags: mysql, sql

After selecting a random row, I want to be able to select n number of records following it. So say for example, if `n = 10`, and I have a table `numbers_table` with 1 column `numbers` having consecutive rows 1 to 10000, if I randomly select 65, I want to return rows 65 to 75. This query rather returns 10 random rows:

```
SELECT `number` FROM `numbers_table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

The following doesn't work too. It returns 65 and then any other consecutive sequence after it (like `65` `90` `91` `92` `93` ...)

```
SELECT `number` FROM `numbers_table` WHERE `number` > 
    (SELECT `number` FROM `numbers_table` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1) 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: what if there fewer than 10 rows with ids 66 to 75?  do you want 10 rows or just the rows with an id within 10 of the random row?   is it ok to select a random row close to the end of the ids so that there are not 10 after id, or does that need to be prevented?

Comment: @ysth in such a scenario, return only rows after selected row. If selected row is the last, return only it

Comment: you didn't answer the first part of my comment above - though the question says "consecutive", so in theory it shouldn't happen.  still good to know how the query should work if it did happen.

Comment: *The following doesn't work too. It returns 65 and then any other consecutive sequence after it (like 65 90 91 92 93 ...)* The problem source is in the ORDER BY clause absence  in outer query. WHERE provides "greater than" but does not provide "immediately after".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to do this

```
SELECT number
FROM numbers_table,
(SELECT FLOOR(RAND()*MAX(number)) num FROM numbers_table) b
WHERE number > b.num
ORDER BY number LIMIT 10;
```

The problem in putting **Rand()** in where clause is it gets computed everytime for each row

Comment: Returns empty result set :/

Comment: @CedricIpkiss what is max num in your table; replace 10000 I think it is generating random number between 0 and 10000 and the number range might not be in your table

Comment: column type is `bigint(20)`

Comment: use explicit join clauses, not the long frowned upon comma-joins

Comment: FLOOR usage is excess... *The problem in putting Rand() in where clause is it gets computed everytime for each row* I doubt... the subquery is not correlated, and server is smart enough to execute it once and reuse its output.

Comment: @Akina i checked it on my local mysql 5.6; and where clause is executed for every row; Floor is just so it returns int value you can go without it was well

Comment: *and where clause is executed for every row* 1) How you have detected this? 2) If the subquery would execute  for each row then new RAND() would calculate for each row - if so then ~ 50% of rows must be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select number
from numbers_table
where number > (
    select number
    from numbers_table
    where number < (
        select min(number) too_high_id from (
            select number from numbers_table order by number desc limit 10
        ) highest_10
    )
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
order by number
limit 11
```

If you don't mind selecting fewer than 11 rows, it's simpler:

```
select number
from numbers_table
where number > (
    select number
    from numbers_table
    order by rand()
    limit 1
)
order by number
limit 11
```

If you have gaps in your numbers and only want rows with numbers within 10 of the randomly selected one, this is best done:

```
select numbers_table.number
from (
    select number as pick
    from numbers_table
    order by rand()
    limit 1
) pick
join numbers_table on number between pick and pick+10
```

These are demonstrated in https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7b954cd24ed140ec52155ed023f3eb61

Comment: Please help me understand better, what does the `min_id` row signify? Did you mean min(id)?

Comment: the version that was there was missing the order by rand() limit 1; see the current version

Comment: (also changed id to number; not sure why I was using id)

Comment: This behaves similar to the second code in my answer (returns `65` `90` `91` `92` `93` ...)

Comment: @CedricIpkiss I hadn't seen your second query; you are missing `order by number`